# Voltage Follower Circuit Output Changes based on Load Resistance

Tags: operational-amplifier, impedance-matching

I am trying to simulate a circuit which can act as a voltage follower for a headlight. I simulated the circuit using CircuitLab.[image: Voltage Follower Circuit]

I simulated two conditions:

1. When headlight resistance is 10 Ohm.
   [image: Time Domain Plot for input and output voltages when lamp resistance is 10 Ohm.]
2. When headlight resistance is 100 Ohm.
   [image: Time Domain Plot for input and output voltages when lamp resistance is 100 Ohm.]

Can you please explain me why I am getting different voltages in these conditions? My initial thought was that the lamp resistance should not have affected the output of the op-amp. Below is the op-amp parameters:
[image: Op-amp Parameters]

Comment: Note that when you use the CircuitLab button on the editor toolbar and "Save and Insert" on the editor an editable schematic is saved in your post. That makes it easy for us to copy and edit in our answers. You don't need a CircuitLab account, no screengrabs, no image uploads, no background grid.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't drive lamps from a humble op-amp. Your load resistance is way too low.

[image]

*Figure 1. Extract from [TL081 datasheet](https://www.st.com/resource/en/datasheet/tl081.pdf).*

You are seeing the voltage across each lamp depending on the op-amp's short-circuit current. The simulator is trying to be realistic.

Comment: Thanks for your explanation.